# How to return data from array who have composite type

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql, pgadmin

I have those tables in my Postgres Database:

```sql
CREATE TYPE endereco AS (
    rua text,
    cidade text,
    estado char(2),
    cep text
);

CREATE TYPE tipo_cliente AS enum('Vip', 'Esp', 'Padrão');

CREATE TABLE cliente (
    codigo int PRIMARY KEY,
    nome text NOT NULL,
    tipo tipo_cliente,
    pontosBonificação decimal,
    descontoPadrao decimal NOT NULL,
    endereco endereco NOT NULL,
    telefone text[]
);

CREATE TYPE mercadoria AS (
    codigo int,
    preco decimal,
    icms decimal
);

CREATE TYPE item_pedido AS (
    numeroItem int,
    quantidade decimal,
    desconto decimal,
    mercadoria mercadoria
);

CREATE TABLE pedido (
    codCliente int references cliente(codigo),
    codigo int primary key,
    data_pedido Date,
    data_entrega Date,
    itemPedido item_pedido[]
);
```

I would like to do 2 querys:

1. Get all pedidos where codigo`s mercadoria = 6
2. Get the total value of pedidos where codCliente = 53

How I can do this?

I don't even the syntax... :(

Comment: Reconsider your data model. This appears to be a case of using arrays of composite types where rows in tables would be more appropriate. In general, composite types should be reserved for abstract concepts like points in space (x, y, z coordinates) or time periods (start time, duration). Tables should be used when the references are to specific instances. Tables provide support for referential integrity and are easier to search.

Comment: Unfortunately this model is an exercise, I can't change it. But I agree with you that's would be better separating those datas in diferentes tables

Comment: Since this is an exercise, I'll try to guide you to the solution without giving it to you. When PostgreSQL creates a table it also creates a composite type with the same name representing the row structure for that table, so you know the syntax for accessing the components. The arrays can be treated as tables using `UNNEST`. With those pieces of information, you should be able to craft a solution to each problem. It might also be useful to explore `JOIN LATERAL`, although that shouldn't be required.